# Use Persistent Volume with loki installed with helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

Do you know how to use the AWS EBS volume prepared in advance as the Persistent Volume of the pod when installing loki with helm?

Should I create a PersistentVolume like the one below and specify the required parameters in persistence: at https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/production/helm/loki/values.yaml?
Do you know the parameters?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata: metadata:
   name: pv-loki
   namespace: loki
spec: spec:
   capacity:
     storage: 50Gi
   accessModes:
     --ReadWriteOnce
   #storageClassName: sc-loki
   awsElasticBlockStore:
     fsType: ext4
     volumeID: vol-<VOL-ID>
```

repo: loki / loki

CHART VERSION: 2.1.1

APP VERSION: v2.0.0

using.